# Request paremeters appear to be null in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, request

This is my jsp:

```
<form method='post' action='/controller'>
     <div >
         <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name-input-field" pattern="[A-Z][a-z]+([ -][A-Z][a-z]+)*" required >
     </div>                        
</form>
```

This is my servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
      req.getParameter("name-input-field");//appears null    
}
```

Please Help me find the mistake.

Comment: First, use your browser's debugging tools to inspect the request that's being sent. (And if possible, use something like Spring MVC instead of handling servlets by hand--it makes life immensely easier, especially with Spring Boot.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `getParameter()` method takes in the `name` attribute of `input` tag and not the `id` attribute. It returns the value of `value` attribute of the `input`.

Add `name="name-input-field"` to your `input` tag to get its value in `Servlet`.

Comment: Can we have same id and name?

Comment: yes @RamzahRehman you can have the same name and id for the same component

Comment: sure, they can be same.

Answer (score 1):

As Yogesh said the req.getParameter uses name, but also you have to know this:

Imagine this scenario:

You have to disable the input option or whatever you could use this in your html:

```
<input type="text" name="ame-input-field" disabled><br>
```

Well Sr you will get a null because a disable input won't be send in your request ;) so be carefull